# Detecting WiFi disconnection with Siri Shortcut automation

Tags: wifi, automation, siri, shortcuts-app

Is it possible to write a Siri Shortcuts script or automation to detect when my phone disconnects from a particular WiFi network? I've seen this posted as an issue on places like Apple discussion forums etc and have trawled the list of scripts and actions but cannot find anything which would perform this or a similar function.

The closest I've got is to detect leaving my home area with geofencing. Not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Geofencing will be the most simple. The most cluttering way would be to create time of day automations individually (spaced at whatever interval you deem best), and each time check which WiFi network you are connected to (or not).

If you want to get complicated, you could write an AppleScript that sends a message to yourself (or email) at intervals, and then you could have a single automation based on the reception of such a signal, which then runs and checks network status.

If you connect to a different WiFi when you disconnect from the target WiFi, you can run an automation that triggers when you connect to that WiFi.

Essentially, there's no easy way to do this. Shortcuts are great for detecting positive actions but not negative ones.