# Siri shortcuts fails with airplane mode

Tags: wifi, automation, siri, shortcuts-app

I'm running iOS 16.0.3 and have created a simple Siri Shortcut automation to switch my phone to airplane mode when it connects to my home WiFi (and another to disable airplane mode when leaving the area - but [that's another story](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448841/detecting-wifi-disconnection-with-siri-shortcut-automation)).

The problem, however, is that these shortcuts don't actual dis/enable airplane mode. The shortcut clearly runs, I see the notification, but nothing happens.

I have other shortcuts which run when detecting that airplane mode is enabled (to go into Dark Mode, for example) but actually de/activating airplane mode appears to be broken.

I have tested by disabling all my automations and only using one automation which turns on airplane more - and again with one which turns off cell data. Neither of these appear to work.

It is as if antenna automations are broken.

Does anyone have a workaround until Apple fixes this or am I mistaken/taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my phone either needed a new battery or a good hard reboot, but this issue is now fixed.

I've posted another [question related to running the automation without user interaction](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449932/avoiding-user-interaction-for-certain-siri-automations).

Comment: Consider marking this answer as accepted to avoid it being bumped by Community user as unanswered.