# Avoiding user interaction for certain Siri automations

Tags: automation, siri, shortcuts-app

I have (finally) managed to setup a [Siri automation which detects when I've left an area](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448844/siri-shortcuts-fails-with-airplane-mode) and switches off my Airplane mode, but it only generates a lock screen notification which I have to tap on to run.

Is it possible to remove this interaction and have it run to completion without human intervention?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to remove this interaction and have it run to completion without human intervention?

### In short, no.

Assuming you are still using the same device as in the [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448844/siri-shortcuts-fails-with-airplane-mode) you have mentionned in this question, it is possible to do what you are trying to do but not with some parameters/actions, which include "Leave" (that's the parameter when you have left an area", which means that you could not disable "Ask Before Running" (+"Don't ask to confirm your choice").

From [Enable or disable a personal automation in Shortcuts on iPhone or iPad (Enable an automation to run without asking)](https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/shortcuts/apd602971e63/ios) :

> The following automations cannot be run automatically:
>
> - Arrive
> - **Leave**
> - Before I Commute
> - Email
> - Message
> - Wi-Fi
> - Bluetooth